# SIMPLE PIE - Get Images in a particular rss feed

Tags: image, simplepie

I am trying this feed http://servicios.elpais.com.uy/formatos/rss/index.asp?seccion=ultmom
throw the simplepie demo page and it works great.
I can get a lot of info of this feed, but I dont know how to get the images and if you try the demo it is possible.

How can I get this images?

PS: I dont mean the feed image, I mean each news image

really thanks

Answer (score 0):

Some versions of RSS/Atom have a thumbnail others don't. If you want to get images all images from a feed you'll need to use something like simple_html_dom.

This question gets asked all the time, someone who knows how StackOverflow and SimplePie work should merge these [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15306738/get-youtube-thumbnail-simplepie).